# PHP Search Multidimensional Array for Value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Country] => Americas [Out_Count] => 14 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Country] => Belgium [Out_Count] => 2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [Country] => China [Out_Count] => 33 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Country] => France [Out_Count] => 7 ) 
)
```

I have a variable as follows:

```
$los = 'Belgium';
```

What I'd like to do is search the array and bring back the value of `Out_Count` to a variable.

I can use the following:

```
$key = array_search($los, array_column($outs, 'Country'));
```

This brings back the Key, in this case `1` for Belgium but I need the `Out_Count` value and I'm utterly stumped on how to achieve this.

Any ideas and thoughts welcomed.

Comment: if `$los = 'Belgium';` then `$los[0]` means `B` not `Belgium`.

Comment: _to achieve this_ `print $outs[$key]['Out_Count'];`

Comment: Will `Country` be unique in the array?

Comment: Not always, no!  Now trying to work out how to deal with that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nice choice of `array_column()`! Just extract an array with `Country` as the key and `Out_Count` as the value:

```
$los = 'Belgium';
$result = array_column($outs, 'Out_Count', 'Country')[$los];
```

To do it your way:

```
$los = 'Belgium';
$key = array_search($los, array_column($outs, 'Country'));
$result = $outs[$key]['Out_Count'];
```

Or:

```
$result = $outs[array_search($los, array_column($outs, 'Country'))]['Out_Count'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array = array(
  array('Country' => 'Americas', 'Out_Count' => 14),
  array('Country' => 'Belgium', 'Out_Count' => 2),
  array('Country' => 'China', 'Out_Count' => 33),
  array('Country' => 'France', 'Out_Count' => 7)
);


function search($array, $key, $value) {
$results = array();
if (is_array($array)) {
    if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value) {
        $results[] = $array;
    }
    foreach ($array as $subarray) {
        $results = array_merge($results, search($subarray, $key, $value));
    }
 }
 return $results;
}
```

Ouput:

```
$Out_Count = search($array, 'Country', 'Belgium');
echo $Out_Count[0]['Out_Count'];   //print 2

$Out_Count = search($array, 'Country', 'France');
echo $Out_Count[0]['Out_Count'];  //print 7
```

In this way,you have the complete array that you have searched and you can access it.

```
print_r($Out_Count);

Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [Country] => Belgium
        [Out_Count] => 2
    )

 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom function like this

```
function my_custom_array_search($array, $search)
{
   foreach($array as $single)
   {
     if($single['Country']==$search)
     {
        return $single['Out_Count'];
     }
   }
   return '';
}
```